# Is it possible to get audio track data from libVLC by using javascript/python

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, libvlc

I am trying to extract audio track information (specifically language of the audio) from a live stream that i will be playing with libVLC . Is it possible to do this in javascript or python without writing new code for a wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about javascript, but the Python wrapper will let you do this.